# Get woocommerce parent product name only

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using this function to get the product name and return it in a short code:

```
public function getProducts() {
        $items =  $this->order->get_items();
        $product = chr(10);
        if(!empty($items)) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $product_item = $item->get_product();
                if ($product_item) {
                    $product =  $item['name'];
                    
                }
            }
        }
        $return['{products}'] = $product;
```

in case of product with variations, I get:

```
parent name - variation name  (eg: shirt - black)
```

but I'd like to get only the parent name.

How can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You should test if the product is a variation, and if so, get the parent product. Then you can get the name.

```php
if ($product_item->is_type('variable')) {
  $parent_product = wc_get_product($product_item->get_parent_id());
  $product = $parent_product->get_name();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason thank you, that's right :-)

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should return the product name:

```
$product_item->get_name();
```